# How can I monitor / limit network traffic used by my app?

Tags: delphi, networking, monitoring, bandwidth

I would like to be able to measure network traffic and limit it.

I'm looking for something that lets me know between two calls how much data has been sent and received. Also, I would like to be able to limit network traffic (in & out) for my app.
Something like the NetLimiter software (great app!) but which I can control from my code.

Do you know some third party components to do this ?

This is meant to be used on a datasnap 2009 thin-client.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Indy, then use the [`TIdInterceptThrottler`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdInterceptThrottler.html) class. Simply set the `BitsPerSec` property.

My understanding is that DataSnap is based on Indy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've take a look at what you said. From what i understand, datasnap is based on Indy on the server side, and on dbexpress on the client side. So, i think that it should be possible to limit/monitor traffic but only on the server. (but that don't seems to be so straightforward)

Comment: Sorry, that's the best I can do. WinPCap is probably worth a closer look. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by the system as a whole (and not the application - it's a bit unclear), you could look at [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org). There are Delphi wrappers available.

Comment: I meant to monitor/limit traffic of the delphi application. Thanks for the link, I didn't know that project at all, it seems very cool.

Answer (score 1):

If your are developing an application on unix-based box such as Linux, you can limit your connection speed using linux's built-in firewall name `iptables`.