# Measure Network Data with Python

Tags: python, networking, traffic-measurement

I'm currently writing a program to shut down a computer when over a period of time (say, half an hour) network traffic is below a certain threshold.

Here's the pseudocode that I've worked will give the correct logic:

```
BEGIN SUBPROGRAM
    loopFlag = True
    Wait 5 minutes    # Allows time for boot and for the machine to settle
    traffic = 0
    WHILE loopFlag = True DO
        FOR sec = 0 to 3600
            traffic += *network.traffic()*
            wait 1 second
        ENDFOR
        IF traffic < trafficThreshold THEN
            loopFlag = False
        ENDIF
    ENDWHILE
    os.ShutDown()
END SUBPROGRAM
```

What I'm looking for is the Python module or library that will allow me to measure this.

Whilst I've [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861586/how-to-measure-network-throughput-during-runtime) [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561999/how-can-i-monitor-limit-network-traffic-used-by-my-app) [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148608/network-traffic-monitor-with-pcapy-in-python) into this, these don't seem to be the sort of functionality I'm after, regardless of their language.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To check the network traffic on your system, i recommend you look into [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
>>> psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
{'lo': iostat(bytes_sent=799953745, bytes_recv=799953745, packets_sent=453698, packets_recv=453698), 
 'eth0': iostat(bytes_sent=734324837, bytes_recv=4163935363, packets_sent=3605828, packets_recv=4096685)}
>>>
```

And to shutdown your OS, if you are on windows check this: [OS Reboot, Shutdown, Hibernate, Sleep, Wakeup (Windows Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673707/os-reboot-shutdown-hibernate-sleep-wakeup-windows-python)

and if you are using `linux`/`unix`, use the `subprocess` module to send the `shutdown`/`reboot` command.

Comment: I'll look into it. I wasn't having trouble with the shutdown, so extra brownie points for this. I'll mark correct if everything works.

Comment: Are each of these stats per second?

Comment: No, these are total stats.

Comment: Note that as of psutil 3.2.2 (at least) the name of this method is net_io_counters.