# Accessing web browser's developer tools using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to access the developer tools of the browser that I'm using (Firefox) using Selenium. I know that you can press F12 to access it, so I'm trying to "press" F12 using Selenium but I'm having some trouble.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('http://google.com')
browser.send_keys(u'\ue03c')
```

But when I do this, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Is there a way to "press" keys without having to focus on an element?

Comment: Why are you trying to access the dev tools with Selenium? This seems like it might be a http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Hi jon, I'm a beginner to python, and my end-goal is to access the dev tools using python. It does seem like I am approaching the problem incorrectly, do you know if there is a better method instead of manually "pressing" F12 using selenium?

Comment: @Michael, what do you want to do **after** dev tools opened?

Comment: That doesn't seem like an actual end goal. What do you intend to *do*? What research have you done, e.g. I found http://stackoverflow.com/q/20401264/3001761 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/36311191/3001761 pretty quickly.

Comment: Hi andersson and jonrsharpe, apologies for not making it clear. After accessing the dev tools, I want to switch over to the Network tab and pull the data relating how much data is being transferred. Essentially just creating a small python tool to just monitor the bandwidth of a browser.

Comment: You won't be able to get data from Network tab with `selenium` as it is not part of a `DOM`. You can try to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958614/measure-network-data-with-python or provide with more details of what data you want to extract